# Retrieving status of JCheckbox inside a JTable

Tags: java, swing

For some reason, i cannot find out what is wrong with my code. Basically

1. I have a counter (total) initialized to 2 in this case
2. Increment to a max of 6, each time a `JCheckbox` is checked (in this case 4 )and throws a message when too much is clicked.
3. At first, it throws null pointer when exactly a total of 6 is checked; but works fine if more than 6 checkboxes are selected, then reduced to 6 with more than one button click.

Can anyone guide me to where it is messing with my head? Thank you very much.

```
public void panelThree(JTable user, JButton save, JButton logout, JButton exit, int j) {
    System.out.println("J in external main is: " + j);
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        boolean arr[] = new boolean[user.getRowCount()];

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int total = j;
            System.out.println("Total in listener is: "+total);
            System.out.println("No of rows: " + user.getRowCount());
            for (int z = 0; z < arr.length; z++) {
                arr[z] = false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < user.getRowCount(); i++) {                  
                if (Boolean.valueOf(user.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3).toString()) == true) {
                    if (arr[i] == false) {
                        arr[i] = true;
                        total++;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (arr[i] == true) {
                        arr[i] = false;
                        total--;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Total is: " + total);
            if (total > 6) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose up to a maximum of " + (6 - j) + " modules");
            } else {
                int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to enroll in these modules?", "Yes", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enrollment Successful");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The line `if (Boolean.valueOf(user.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3).toString()) == true)` seems to be responsible for all the error all the edit i am making console says null pointer at that line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I've corrected my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table seems to contain null values. So you need to consider it in your check. Something like this:

```
if (user.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3) == Boolean.TRUE)
```

If my suggestion don't work please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can also reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl it's the same as SSCCE but the link is shorter :).

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Does this structure seems better?

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy You sir... You are a saviour... Worked perfectly thank you very very much :D